# immutables typescript type definitions: why is concat operating on any?

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

I don't understand why [the definition of `concat`](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/b7238a7f2ec421fbf103d4d1e6138b9d3d4e8b3e/type-definitions/Immutable.d.ts#L3529) in `Collection<K, V>` for instance uses `any`:

```
concat(...valuesOrCollections: Array<any>): Collection<any, any>;
```

why couldn't it be:

```
concat(...valuesOrCollections: Array<V>): Collection<K, V>;
```

?

Comment: Maybe because you can concatenate arrays of different types

Comment: Probably not.. If i don't mix types (90% of the cases esp for typescript users) then i need to cast?? At least i'd like an extra type-safe version then. Plus the key type K at least should stay the same if not the value type?

Comment: (in the end @AlekseyL. was quite close to the correct answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've tried to modify the type definition in the source of immutables and run the tests, and I see now why they have the type definition they do.

They want to support basically everything, as in (obviously) the original JS api. For instance adding object properties:

```
  it('concats objects to keyed seq', () => {
    let a = Seq({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});
    let b = {d: 4, e: 5, f: 6};
    expect(a.concat(b).toObject()).toEqual({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6});
  });
```

adding multiple values directly as parameters:

```
  it('concats values', () => {
    let a = Seq.of(1, 2, 3);
    expect(a.concat(4, 5, 6).size).toBe(6);
    expect(a.concat(4, 5, 6).toArray()).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
  });
```

or even adding multiple arrays in parameters:

```
  it('concats multiple arguments', () => {
    let a = Seq.of(1, 2, 3);
    let b = [4, 5, 6];
    let c = [7, 8, 9];
    expect(a.concat(b, c).size).toBe(9);
    expect(a.concat(b, c).toArray()).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
  });
```

To get this in a type-safe way in typescript we'd need multiple overloads I guess (`concatCollection`, `concatValues`, `concatProperties` and so on).

PS: to be fair the parameter name in the original definition was a good hint: `valuesOrCollections`

*Update:* after i opened a small PR, the maintainer implemented [an exhaustive fully type-safe solution](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/commit/e2ee51deb5141648920626ddf361caa90d51d637).

Comment: Actually we can have overloads with same name, but different parameters. Have a look at [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Bar%3CV%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20concat(...values%3A%20V%5B%5D)%3AV%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20concat(...collections%3A%20Array%3CV%5B%5D%3E)%3AV%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20concat(...values%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3AV%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%20%3D%20new%20Bar%3Cnumber%3E()%3B%0D%0Ax.concat(1%2C%202%2C%203)%3B%0D%0Ax.concat(%5B1%5D%2C%20%5B2%5D%2C%20%5B3%5D)%3B)

Comment: wow thanks for the hint @AlekseyL. ! Submitted a PR: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/pull/1151

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why that's the signature, but you should be able to [augment the module/interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to add a generic signature.
Something like:

```
declare module "immutable" {
    module Collection {
       interface Collection<K, V> {
           concat(...valuesOrCollections: Array<V>): Collection<K, V>;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally the original type definition would be good already (I'll probably open them a bug if noone can come up with a good reason why it is like it is)... but I tried your solution now and I get `Invalid module name in augmentation, module 'Immutable' cannot be found.`. I do have in my node_modules `immutable/dist/immutable.d.ts` and it does contain that module. I import from immutables like that at the top of my file: `import {Map, List, Seq, Collection} from "immutable";`.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was imported as `import ... from "Immutable"`. The names must be the same. Changed it to `declare module "immutable"` in my answer.

Comment: Better now! But I had to remove the spread syntax to make it work (maybe that's why they use `any`) -- `concat(valuesOrCollections: Array<V>): Collection<K, V>`. But then something is wrong. On the `Collection` that I get out I get only one function: `concat`. So... `List(something).concat(...)` and on this I can only apply `concat` again. So it seems it differentiates between the `Collection` this returns (the expanded interface which contains only `concat`) and the real `Collection` from the upstream library.

Comment: Can you add the code you're using which causes the problem to your question so I'll be able to test things myself?

Comment: sorry, we're veering a bit off-topic here so i created a gist: https://gist.github.com/emmanueltouzery/e12815e0ae52315d53d3814afd7dd1c3 -- this doesn't compile for me and I would expect it to. removing the module augment part, it compiles normally. But yeah I think the type definition is wrong in immutables, will open a bug, waiting a little more in case someone comes up with an explanation

Comment: I'm not getting an error with the code including the augmentation (with the spread syntax though). But it works without it as well so the augmentation is pointless...   Opening an issue is probably the right thing to do.

Comment: I don't agree the augmentation is pointless. Sure, it compiled but the result of the expression was Collection<any,any> in other words the next expression is not type-safe, I need casts to continue, also I can put basically any expression in the `concat` parameter, while I'd like to constrain that for type-safety. Otherwise seems like I won't open a bug, see the answer I added to the question myself just now. I guess i'll maybe try to augment with other type-safe methods instead of changing this one, maybe request immutables upstream to include them.